# How to show spreedX client ApplicationIndicator?

Tags: 11.10, unity, indicator, python, gsettings

For my job I require the use of the spreedX client which allows me to share my desktop when using the Spreed web conferencing environment (www.spreed.com). In pre-Unity Ubuntu versions, this application's indicator worked perfectly. However, it doesn't play nice with Unity (it doesn't show), not even when adding the magic

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`.

So I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, but I did find the (presumable) source of the client: https://github.com/andreashe/mygitsite/tree/master/spreedX.

I'm assuming that for an (experienced?) Python developer, it shouldn't be hard to fix the app by using the guidelines which I found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators). Unfortunately, I'm no Python developer, let alone an experienced one :-(

But perhaps there are other solutions which I did not think about? Of course, I will contact Spreed and ask them to fix this, but if they won't (or it takes them forever) I would love to have some more options...

Comment: Well the funny part is... it's working after a reboot (however, I now also have a double battery indicator). So should I reboot (or log off/on) every time I change something with gsettings?

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but there's no need - fortunately I was 'wise' enough to write down the previous settings and restore it from there. After logging off and back on, it's now working as expected. I've used the following string: gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'spreedX', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier']".

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jorge and the fact that I needed to reboot my machine for some other reason, I noticed that just running

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'spreedX', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Wine', 'Update-notifier']"
```

isn't enough to make it work. You also have to log out and back in again. Stupid beginner mistake - I know, but one easily made.

It would be 'nice' if gsettings would prompt the user with something like *"You need to log off and back in again in order to take these changes into effect."* when setting stuff like this. On the other hand, IMHO the user shouldn't be required to practice such voodoo for such a simple task in the first place...

Comment: If anyone would stumble upon this question some day, wondering why the default SpreedX client stops working after 30-60 seconds when sharing your screen - there is a 'special build' of the spreedx client availabe for Ubuntu 11.10. Spreed support can help you with this, but I'll see if I can post the direct link.

Answer (score 2):

Later spreedX clients support Unity just fine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.spreed.com/linux/spreedx/deb
wget -qO- http://dl.spreed.com/struktur-debian-package-sign-01-public.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spreedx
```